# Create hello world page dynamically with jQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### Edit

I don't understand why people down vote without actually trying the problem. I will rewrite the question trying to explain my self more clearly. Sorry if I explain my self incorrectly.

I have a simple hello world page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="c">

        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header"> <h1 style="font-size: 150%;"> My Title </h1></div>
            <br />  <br />

            <div data-role="Number">
                <p>
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 310%;">
                        Hello Wold</h1>
                </p>
            </div>            
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### and it renders like:

[image]

(that's why I tag it jquery I want the jquery look and feel of it)

Note the page renders fine. The problem is that I will like to place that html dynamically. I get the content with the help of ajax as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="c">
        <!-- Content will be replaced -->               
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        url: 'someUrl',
        success: function (result) {

            // result should equal =
            result= '<div data-role="page"> <div data-role="header"> <h1 style="font-size: 150%;"> My Title </h1></div> <br /> <br /> <div data-role="Number"> <p> <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 310%;"> Hello Wold</h1> </p> </div> </div>';
            $('$c').append( result );

        } 
    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I run that nothing renders!. I will like to know which jquery function is responsible for styling the html. I will like to execute it again once my ajax response gets back.

Comment: Why is this question marked jQuery?

Comment: @Shmiddty I'm guessing because the jQuery library is used, that's enough to tag it with jQuery...which I don't agree with

Comment: Works when the jquery-mobile script is removed [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/829Nv/)

Comment: it is mark as jquery because the styling does not work without that library.

Comment: I don't mind getting neg points but why is this question down voted ?

Comment: That page get's the jquery look and feel that is what I am trying to achive. Without that library I would not have a problem...

Answer (score 4):

I think the real problem is that you cannot have a `<script>` block outside/after of `<html>`. Try moving it to right before `</body>`.

And there's no need for the `setTimeout` unless you actually want it to wait an extra second before running your code.

The important thing is that you need to run the code *after* your `<div id="c">` element. That could mean right after it, or at the end of the `<body>`. In your case, your page is simple enough that "right after it" is the same as the "end of the `<body>`".

Nonetheless, you need to have the `<script>` inside of the `<html>`, preferably inside of `<head>` or `<body>` (I've seen it work when it was placed in between `<head>` and `<body>` but I wouldn't recommend that.

Just as a suggestion, since you are using jQuery, you might as well take advantage of its DOM manipulation. Instead of using `DOMElement.innerHTML =`, try using the jQuery selector for selecting by ID (`#`) and its `.html()` method:

```
var htmlContent = '<div data-role="page"> <div data-role="header"> <h1 style="font-size: 150%;"> My Title </h1></div> <br /> <br /> <div data-role="Number"> <p> <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 310%;"> Hello Wold</h1> </p> </div> </div>';
$("#c").html(htmlContent);
```

Using `.html()` isn't always the correct choice, but should be for you since you are simply including HTML. Another option is to use `.append(htmlContent)`.

Comment: the setTimout is simulating an ajax call